# Color Excel Cells in one shot using two dimensional array

Tags: .net, excel, export-to-excel

Is there any way to assign two dimensional array of colors directly to excel cells?

In one shot we can assign cell values using `Range.Value=Values[,]`, but I am not able to assign `Colors[,]` to these cells in one shot. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:-

Step 1: Assign `Colors` array to Excel Cells.

```
yourRangeObject.Value = Colors;
```

Step 2: Write macro to color selected range of colors in a *System.String*

```
 private static string GetMacro(int lastCellRowNum, int lastCellColNum)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Sub FormatSheet()" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(" + lastCellRowNum + ", " + lastCellColNum + ")).Select " + "\n");
        sb.Append("  For Each c In Selection" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  c.Interior.Color = HEXCOL2RGB(c.Value)" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  c.Borders.Color = HEXCOL2RGB(\"#FFDEDDDD\")" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Next" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Selection.ClearContents" + "\n");
        sb.Append("End Sub" + "\n");

        sb.Append("Public Function HEXCOL2RGB(ByVal HexColor As String) As String" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Dim Red As String, Green As String, Blue As String " + "\n");
        sb.Append("  HexColor = Replace(HexColor, \"#\", \"\")" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Red = Val(\"&H\" & Mid(HexColor, 1, 2))" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Green = Val(\"&H\" & Mid(HexColor, 3, 2))" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  Blue = Val(\"&H\" & Mid(HexColor, 5, 2))" + "\n");
        sb.Append("  HEXCOL2RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)" + "\n");
        sb.Append("End Function");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Step 3: Run macro written in Step 2

```
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBComponent module = null;
module = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add( Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule );
module.CodeModule.AddFromString(GetMacro(lastCellRowNum, lastCellColNum));
workbook.Application.Run("FormatSheet", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Step 4: Assign `Values` array to Excel cells.

```
yourRangeObject.Value = Values;
```

Thats it...in two shots you can color code your excel cells.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases like this I use  Copy and PasteSpecial formats for blocks of cells, but if you need dynamically and arbitrarily changing colours that won't work.

Comment: I just need to assign colors placed inside 2 dimensional array to excel cells in one shot.
For example:- Using following array I wish to color 4 cells(2 rows and 2 columns) in my excel sheet.
--> Cells[,]{ {"Color1", "Color2"}, {"Color3, "Color4"} }

Comment: The Excel Object model does not allow this, so I would suggest you assign colours individually to the 4 cells the first time you need this, then copy the 4 cells to the clipboard and use PasteSpecial formats for all subsequent sets of 4 cells.